# Mailgun Attachment not attaching

Tags: python, mailgun

I'm having an issue where my attachments aren't sending with the emails (people just get an email with the designated message but no attachment). I'm not getting any runtime errors so it would seem this would be a server error. Any ideas?

Code below:

```
return requests.post(
    sender_info['MAIL_URL'],
    auth=('api', sender_info['MG_API']),
    files=[(
        ("attachment", attachment), 
        ("attachment", open("./Expense Transfer Form.pdf")),
    )],
    data={
        'from': sender_info['SENDER'],
        'to': recipient,
        'cc': ccemail,
        'subject': subject,
        'text': message,
        'attachment': "./Expense Transfer Form.pdf",
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your files part is malformed it should be a list with multiple tuples inside

```
files = [("attachment", ('attachement1',attachment,'text/pdf')),
("attachment, ('expense Transfer Form', open('Expense Transfer Form.pdf', 'rb'),'text/pdf'))]
```

where the tuple is of (form_fieldname, file_info)

you can check on multipart/form-data on python docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files).
Request object is not finding you files to be of multipart which is required in mailgun attachments